# Where to ask which Stack Exchange website is correct for my question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The title says it, where should one ask about the correct Stack Exchange website to ask their question if they aren't sure?

For example, I want to discuss why it is a popular opinion that North-Koreans would eat grass, when it would make much more sense for starving people to eat insects. Or, I want to ask about instant and painless suicide devices that would erase any trace of a human DNA, and current death penalty technology, or I want to ID a painting from a tattoo, etc.

So, where to ask "where to ask"?

Comment: Edit your question to **include a specific example** and leave the [site-recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) and any other appropriate tags. Change the last two words of your title ("my question") to a **very** brief summary. Replace the body with: "I am interested in finding a Stack Exchange site where I can ask about ...". ***If*** your only question is "where to ask" but you have no specific request this will be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag here on Meta Stack Exchange exists for exactly this reason. According to the tag wiki excerpt:

> After looking through the site list, https://stackexchange.com/sites, don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network? Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask, and the community will help you find the appropriate site. Please phrase your question explicitly as a site recommendation, or it might be closed as blatantly off-topic.

So, basically, if you can't find the right site, ask for a site recommendation. Make sure that it's clear you're asking where to ask X, not actually asking X. MSE gets a lot of blatantly off-topic questions every day, and your question may be closed if it's not clear that it's a site rec.

This question you asked is actually a good example of a site recommendation. It's clear that it's a site recommendation, it has the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag, it's got a good example of what you want to ask, and it's got a fair amount of detail.

Comment: Wanna throw in a duplicate vote?